# c# How to determine if key was pressed in different keyboard settings

Tags: c#, keyboard

When keyobard in "Region and language" is set to "English (United States)" - and user press Shift + 2 - in textbox appears "#", but when keyboard is set to i.e. "English (United Kingdom)" - and user press Shift + 2 - in textbox appears "£".

I would like to compare such two strings: "abc#DEF" and "abc£DEF" - and get info that these are equal.

Obviously - I would like to be independent on all keyboard settings.

How to do this?